# Using light/dark themed icons in VS Code Webview

Tags: vscode-extensions

Is there a way to correctly light/dark theme webview content that is not textual? VS Code automatically sets the style of my webview html *body* to reflect light/dark change, but that only applies to foreground/background colors of text or tables, etc but not to svg images used for buttons.

Note that the related question 
[Detect light/dark theme programatically in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257911/detect-light-dark-theme-programatically-in-visual-studio-code) goes as far as deriving style of custom Webview content from the `<body class="vscode-light|dark|high-contrast">`.

Consider webview, which shows an icon that acts as a clickable button:

```html
<img src="images/light/chevron-up.svg" onclick="expandView()"/>
```

**The problem:** the `/light/` directory needs to be replaced by `/dark/` when the user changes the theme.

Theoretically, I could construct this `src` attribute using the `document.body.class`, which indicates the current theme, but I cannot, because the `src` attribute must be created using the `Webview.asWebviewUri(...)` API before it is assigned to the `webview.html` as static html source.

Also theoretically, I could have a [script running in the Webview to detect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58695555/1159548) the `document.body.class` change (caused by the user switching the theme later) and re-apply the new theme, when the user changes it. But that would not work, because the very same `img.src` attribute is at runtime `undefined`, when running inside the Webview. So I cannot just replace the theme folder in the Uri.

**Update:**
I only found a clunky solution: to define each icon twice, use a custom `theme` xml attribute and use a script to show/hide the right icons when the theme changes:

```html
<img src="images/light/chevron-up.svg" theme="light" onclick="expandView()" style="display: inherit"/>
<img src="images/dark/chevron-up.svg" theme="dark" onclick="expandView()" style="dispay: none"/>
```

The duplication is undesirable for maintainability reasons. That is where I ran out of options. Any ideas?