# Programmatically detect light vs dark colour theme

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible programmatically to detect if the current theme is light or dark in VSCode?

**Use Case:**

I am developing a VSCode extension which is going to add [Hovers](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Hover) to the editor, and I would like to have icons in the hovers. However, the background of the hover changes based on the current colour theme, so I need to choose the icons to display based on the colour theme.

Several other places in VSCode you are able to specify icons urls in the form:

```
let icon = {
    light: "uri for light icon",
    dark: "uri for dark icon",
};
```

so clearly VSCode has a notion of light vs dark themes.

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257911/detect-light-dark-theme-programatically-in-visual-studio-code) but AFAIK that answer only applies to webviews, and this issue is also brought up in [this VSCode issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/7589#issuecomment-236490559) after it was closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of VS code 1.40, there is no API for this. Please [file a feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose).

If you really, really want this info today though, you can read the current user's `"workbench.colorTheme"` setting and map this to dark/light. Instead of hardcoding this mapping, look it up by looping through the `contributes` of all known extensions using `vscode.extensions.all.map(ext => ext.packageJSON)`. Here's an example theme contribution (the property you are interested in is `uiTheme`):

```
{
    ...
    "contributes": {
        "themes": [
            {
                "label": "Red",
                "uiTheme": "vs-dark",
                "path": "./themes/Red-color-theme.json"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate you taking the time to respond. I actually went to file a feature request yesterday, and realized there was already an issue describing exactly what Im looking for here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/46940